# объявление переменных

Tags: c++

можно ли объявить переменную, указав тип через консоль?

Comment: Простите, а что вы хотите добиться? Допустим, такая возможность есть - что это вам даст? Как вы хотите этим воспользоваться? строго это невозможно, но можно ведь и сымитировать :)

Comment: В принципе, можно. Если вы по введенным данным сформируете исходный код, откомпилируете его и подключите к текущему исполняемому коду

Answer (score 4):

C++ - это строго-типизированный язык, а поэтому типы всех переменных должны быть известны на этапе компиляции

Answer (score 0):

Можно. К примеру, запросите ввод строки (тип переменной). Затем, в зависимости от типа, объявите её и запросите ввод значения. К примеру, на первый пункт был получен ответ "string". После этого было произведено объявление переменной и запрошен ввод строки.

Comment: По-моему, ТС имеет в виду не совсем это. Если не совсем не это...

Comment: @Harry, а что тогда он имеет в виду?

Comment: @ЧижевскийДаниил, видимо он хочет *динамических* templates

Comment: @Harry, пусть точнее сформулирует вопрос)

Comment: Как я понимаю, он хочет странного :) - а именно указывать тип переменной во время выполнения программы. Возможно, я неправ. К сожалению, автор задал вопрос и исчез, так что мы вынуждены использовать хрустальные шары и ясновидение :)

Comment: Нее... Рандомизация)